# Number of real solutions of a cubic equation without using derivatives

Tags: functions, continuity

The problem is to find the number of real solutions of a cubic equation. This exercise is in a book, in the chapter about functions, limits and continuity. This chapter is before the chapter about derivatives therefore I assume that they cannot be used to solve the exercise.

$$f(x) = x^3-9x^2+24x-17 = 0$$

Factoring it as $x(x^2-9x+24)-17$ and since $x^2-9x+24$ is always positive we can conclude that there are no solutions in $[-\infty,0]$. Since $x^2-9x+24$ is monotonically increasing in $[4.5,+\infty]$ then $f(x)$ also is. Given that $f(4.5) < 0$ we can conclude that there is an unique solution in $[4.5,+\infty]$. How to study the function in $[0,4.5]$?

Comment: Just compute $f(n)$ for $n=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$

Answer (score 3):

Easiest, I think, to just look for sign changes.  We note that $$f(1)=-1\;\;f(2)=3\;\;f(3)=1\;\;f(4)=-1\;\;f(5)=3$$

It follows that there are real roots in each of the intervals $[1,2],\;[3,4],\;[4,5]$.  As a cubic can't have more than three roots, the answer is $\fbox 3$.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#The_nature_of_the_roots) and following case distinctions?
$$
\Delta = 18abcd -4b^3d + b^2c^2 - 4ac^3 - 27a^2d^2
$$
with $a = 1$, $b=-9$, $c=24$, $d=-17$ we get
$$
\Delta = 1682613 > 0
$$
which means three real distinct roots.

Answer (score 0):

$f(2) > 0$ and $f(4)<0$, so $f$ has a zero in $[2, 4]$.